# An exponential integral over a closed convex polytope

Tags: reference-request, integration, convex-polytopes, polyhedra, 0-1-matrices

For any $T\geq 2$, let us define the polyhedron $S$ given by
\begin{align*}
S:=\{\underline{t}:=(t_0,t_1,t_{2},t_{3},t_{4},t_{5},t_{6},t_{7})\in [0,+\infty)^{8}:A\underline{t}\leq (\log T)\textbf{1}\}
\end{align*}
where 
$$A:=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix} $$
and $\textbf{1}$ is the vector with each component equal to $1$.

I computed the following integral and I found the value: $$\int_{S}e^{<\underline{t},\textbf{1}>}\ d\underline{t}\geq c T^2 (\log T)^{4},$$
where $c$ is a positive constant (actually, it is possible to show an asymptotic for such integral of the same shape).

Here I am not focusing on the exact value of such integral but only on a sharp lower bound, as $T\longrightarrow +\infty$.

Since I am interested in a higher dimensional generalization of such problem, in which I need to lower bound the same integral but over a polyhedron defined by a $2k\times2^k$ matrix, I was wondering whether it was already known a general approach to handle such integrals. In particular, I am looking for references where similar problems have been tackled or a general theory about them has been developed.

For the special above example it is of course possible to produce the above lower bound by hand. However, a more general approach, perhaps feasible to aforementioned generalizations, could be to first suitably restricting each variable $t_k$ into intervals of lenght $\geq c_k \log T$, for any $k=0,\dots, 7$ and certain positive constants $c_k$, and then, using that $\text{rank}(A)=4$, expressing $4$ variables in terms of the others, thus leaving us with an integral on $8-4=4$ free variables. I am not sure though how much this strategy can be really formalized in practice.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!